# Number of python function calls drastically increases when run heroku on the web vs heroku locally?

Tags: python, heroku, cprofile

I've verified that the input files and the code is exactly the same when I run Heroku locally and Heroku on the web.  I checked and checked and checked again because I couldn't believe the results.

When I run cprofile locally, I get this:

```
PATH: '/array_summary/'
         2830886 function calls (2804702 primitive calls) in 2.710 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time, call count
   List reduced from 1530 to 30 due to restriction <30>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   586965    0.773    0.000    1.009    0.000 /home/redacted/graph_node_store.py:23(distance_squared)
     7444    0.409    0.000    1.537    0.000 /home/redacted/graph_node_store.py:28(find_coordinate)
  1185414    0.238    0.000    0.238    0.000 /home/redacted/subarray_graph.py:64(coordinate)
```

When I run cprofile on the web, I get this:

```
 PATH: '/array_summary/' 
           67343081 function calls (67255889 primitive calls) in 128.422 seconds 

     Ordered by: internal time, call count 
     List reduced from 1439 to 30 due to restriction <30> 
     ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function) 
   13485728   35.795    0.000   54.904    0.000 /app/redacted/graph_node_store.py:23(distance_squared) 
   28610118   20.720    0.000   20.720    0.000 /app/redacted/graph_node.py:21(coordinate) 
      10049   17.080    0.002   99.673    0.010 /app/redacted/graph_node_store.py:28(find_coordinate)
```

The total function calls increase from 2.8m to 67m (23x), and the distance checks increase from 0.6m to 13m (22x).

What could *possibly* be causing this?  I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried following the call chain upwards to find out the caller of each function, and the caller of that, and the caller of _that_?

Comment: How, exactly, do you "run Heroku locally" and "Heroku on the web"?

Comment: @JohnGordon `brew install heroku` and it emulates the way heroku runs the application on the web. At least, that's what I understand. I haven't printed out callstacks for each of those function calls, but `distance_squared` is only called from one function, which is only called from one function, etc. I'm dumbfounded why the numbers can be so completely different, though.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your web server automatically start many instances of your app, in anticipation of heavy traffic?

Comment: @JohnGordon From my understanding, no, it's on demand.  That could account for more modules being loaded, etc, and more overall function calls, but my `distance_squared` function should still be called the exact same number of times for the same input file.